# How to get nested Selects in a where_in clause in CodeIgniter's datamapper?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a MySQL query that I've gotten to work in PhpMyAdmin/MySQL Workbench.

```
SELECT *
FROM (`medfacts`)    
JOIN `categories_medfacts` ON `categories_medfacts`.`medfact_id` = `medfacts`.`id`    
where title in (    
 select medfacts.title from medfacts    
JOIN `categories_medfacts` ON `categories_medfacts`.`medfact_id` = `medfacts`.`id`    
 where categories_medfacts.category_id = 2    
)     
or title in (    
 select medfacts.title from medfacts    
JOIN `categories_medfacts` ON `categories_medfacts`.`medfact_id` = `medfacts`.`id`    
 where categories_medfacts.category_id = 3    
)
```

(The query gets all medfacts that are listed in the join table categories_medfacts with the given category IDs.)

I now need to transfer it to my CodeIgniter project in a way that allows my program to add as many Having clauses as needed. What I have so far generates the query mostly right.

```
function list_by_category($cat, $module) {
    /* Get a list of the Medfacts entries that have this category.         *
     */
    $this->db->join('categories_medfacts', 'categories_medfacts.medfact_id = medfacts.id');
    $this->where('medfacts.module_id', $module);
    /* If the category is an array, just get the articles that fall under all categories.
     * This shouldn't be more than a handful deep.
     */
    if (is_array($cat)) {
        foreach ($cat as $field => $value) {
            $this->where_in('title', "select medfacts.title from medfacts JOIN `categories_medfacts` ON `categories_medfacts`.`medfact_id` = `medfacts`.`id` where categories_medfacts.category_id = {$value}");
        }
    } else {
        $this->where('categories_medfacts.category_id', $cat);
    }
    $this->select('medfacts.title');
    return $this->get();
}
```

However, I can't get it to not escape the nested Select statements, and end up with this:

```
SELECT `medfacts`.`title`
FROM (`medfacts`)
JOIN `categories_medfacts` ON `categories_medfacts`.`medfact_id` = `medfacts`.`id`
WHERE ( 
`medfacts`.`module_id` = '2'
AND `medfacts`.`title` IN ('select medfacts.title from medfacts JOIN `categories_medfacts` ON `categories_medfacts`.`medfact_id` = `medfacts`.`id` where categories_medfacts.category_id = 2') 
AND `medfacts`.`title` IN ('select medfacts.title from medfacts JOIN `categories_medfacts` ON `categories_medfacts`.`medfact_id` = `medfacts`.`id` where categories_medfacts.category_id = 3') 
 )
AND `medfacts`.`site_id` = 1
```

Notice the quotes around the nested select in the where in clause.

Is there a way to get Datamapper to not escape that nested select? Or, is there a better way to achieve the same goal? Or am I stuck writing the query myself?

I'm using CI 1.7.2 and Datamapper DMZ 1.7.1 (updating is currently out of the question) on PHP5 severs.

**Edit:** I am aware that a simple `or where` would return articles that match each `where` case. However, that's not what I need. I need only results that fall under all given categories. With my current setup, an `or where` returns too many results (includes ones that only fall under one of the listed categories), and `and where` doesn't return anything (nor would it ever, as the category_id can't both be "2" and "3").

Also, I found a JOIN, such as below also works in MySQL, but I can't translate it into CI, either (I didn't post it, because I thought the `where in` above was the cleaner method).

```
SELECT *    
FROM (`medfacts`)    
JOIN `categories_medfacts` ON `categories_medfacts`.`medfact_id` = `medfacts`.`id`    
join (    
    select medfacts.title, medfacts.id from medfacts    
JOIN `categories_medfacts` ON `categories_medfacts`.`medfact_id` = `medfacts`.`id`    
    where categories_medfacts.category_id = 2    
)  m1    
on m1.id = medfacts.id    
 join (    
    select medfacts.title, medfacts.id from medfacts    
JOIN `categories_medfacts` ON `categories_medfacts`.`medfact_id` = `medfacts`.`id`    
    where categories_medfacts.category_id = 3    
) m2    
on m2.id = medfacts.id    
where `medfacts`.`module_id` = '2'    
and medfacts.site_id = 1
```

Comment: WOW! I haven't read the question but you are doing multiple sub-queries AND joins just to match multiple category IDs `categories_medfacts.category_id`?! I suggest you ask how to optimize that query!

Comment: Perhaps you should read the question, then? I did ask if there was a better way to achieve the same result.

Comment: what would this query return: `SELECT * FROM medfacts,categories_medfacts WHERE categories_medfacts.medfact_id = medfacts.id AND categories_medfacts.category_id IN (2,3)`

Comment: ifaour: Too many records. I only need records that are categorized under both category 2 and 3, not 2 or 3. Your query gets records matching 2 or 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is only one way I found to perform subselects in CI - http://heybigname.com/2009/09/18/using-code-igniters-active-record-class-to-create-subqueries/

however, some time ago I have been warned by a very skilled programmer (my boss actually :D) that subselects are quite slow and performing multiple separate selects or trying to do a join instead (where possible) is much quicker... didn't have an opportunity to benchmark it, so take it just as a minor suggestion :)

Comment: I have no issue doing it a completely different way if necessary, but I haven't yet come up with a better way. The initial query I had come up with used joins instead of where...in, but CI/DMZ still didn't like doing what I tried. I'll try again with the help of your link (thank you for that).

Comment: The method provided in your link didn't work as written in that link (my subquery returns more than one value), so I modified it to try to use that method of creating the query in a JOIN. Using the method in your link to create a subquery, then adding it in via a JOIN works and gets me the needed results (it generates the SQL that I've added to my question). I'm not sure how efficient it is, though.

Comment: try MySQL EXPLAIN to see how your query performs - if you have indexes set correctly and the select time is ok, you might not need to optimize this further - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: ... also, I'd suggest using slow query log and see if your query doesn't appear there (either on your local server or the production server - the latter is much more efficient but you can still emulate multiple requests locally if needed) - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: Let me rephrase that - I don't know how efficient it is compared to alternative methods (assuming there are any, other than the where...in). From what I can tell, this method is fairly efficient, all things considered, but we'll see when we get real data into it and see how it scales.